# Run multiple pages (Tabs) in one Test in parallel with Playwright TS

Tags: typescript, parallel-processing, playwright-test

Currently I am trying to run the logins on multiple websites in playwright in different pages (tabs) in parallel. The logic behind it is, that we have multiple login pages with the same design and we want to check if the login ist possible to verify that the page is accessible. I do not want to write a asynchronere test function for each URL but I also do not want to run them in order.  is there a way to handle multiple pages in one test in parallel?

I tried using the browsercontext and give the page to another function without await and created a new page for the next url but without success.